# Regex to match -1:+1 pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to make regex for **-1:+1** pattern, where 1 is any integer?

I need to use it in preg_match(), but my regex skills are none...

Comment: Would "-1:+2" or "+1:+10" match the pattern you need?

Comment: I added the [php] tag as per the regex tag's documentation: "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using." If this is incorrect, please feel free to use the "rollback" feature to restore your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$subject = "-100:+100";
$pattern = '/-\d+:\+\d+/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

\d refers to digit, 
+ means one or more of preceding
so \d+ is one or more digits and so on

**Not Tested**

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex

```
-\d+:\+\d+
```

It matches a `-` followed by one or more digits followed by a `:` followed by a `+` followed by one or more digits.

Use the following if you want both to be the same integer

```
-(\d+):\+\1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match single digits with `\d`. For 1 or more digits use `\d+`. You have to escape other characters, so it's `\-` and `\+` for matching these characters. But I recommend reading a regex tutorial for the language you are using – it's not as hard as it looks!

Answer (score 0):

if you need real numbers (e.g. 001 should not be matched) use this pattern

`/-([1-9]\d*|0):\+([1-9]\d*|0)/`

`|` means or
`[1-9]` means one of the numbers between 1 and 9 (inclusive)
`\d*` means a digit 0 or more times